# UFW blocks traffic in NAT

Tags: 14.04, ufw, nat

I've created a VM guest with libvirt with the default NAT Bridge. (Host and Guest Ubuntu 14.04 Server) 
After creating allow rules for SSH and enabling ufw - on the guest - i can't connect to the guest anymore.

From syslog (of the guest):

```
Oct  6 17:36:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 5969.693057] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0   
OUT=MAC=52:54:00:ea:b5:2e:fe:54:00:ea:b5:2e:08:00 SRC=192.168.122.1
DST=192.168.122.152 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=5379 DF PROTO=TCP
SPT=34376 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Status of ufw(on the guest):

```
root@ubuntu:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    148.251.139.136 22/tcp
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    148.251.139.133 22/tcp
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    141.7.0.0/16 22/tcp
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.122.0/24 22/tcp
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.122.1 22/tcp
```

148.251.139.136 is the IP of the Host, Guest is 192.168.122.152. I have no idea why ufw blocks the allowed IP of the Host/NAT.

If i disable ufw on the guest i can connect from the host via SSH without problems.

edit: for clarification, these are logs of the guest. NAT routing is working. The problem seems to be on the VM guest side.

Comment: `disabled (routed)`?

Comment: I second davids statement. You would have to allow routing especially if the host has a different IP network than the guest. For example 192.168.1.96 255.255.255.0 would not connect to 192.168.2.33 255.255.255.0 unless there was a router with BGP enabled

Comment: Routing on the KVM Host is enabled, i can connect via ssh to the guest if i disable the guests ufw.

Comment: As long as the guest isn't a router, you don't need to allow `routed`.  That is it can talk to all nets that it is directly connected to. And if it want to connect to computers that are on other LAN:s, it just need to connect to a router that is on a network that the guest is connected too.  No need to allow `routed` for that.  Just allow outgoing for the protocol and IP-addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after much trial and error i finally found the solution:

instead of:

```
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.122.0/24 22/tcp
```

the correct rule should be:

```
 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    192.168.122.0/24
```

i mistakenly specified the source port instead of the destination port. This was caused by using the short form  of the ufw allow command:

```
ufw allow from 192.168.122.0/24 port 22  proto tcp
```

correct form:

```
ufw allow from 192.168.122.0/24 to any port 22 proto tcp
```