# ufw block error seen in journalctl -xe command

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw, openconnect

I'm newbie in networking and system security. I am trying to create `openconnect` server which tutorial is found in [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openconnect-vpn-server-ocserv-ubuntu-20-04-lets-encrypt) link. I have also seen the similar issues like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533119/ufw-blocks-traffic-in-nat), but they don't make sense to me.

From the latter link, I have tried the following commands:

```
ufw allow from any to any port 80 proto tcp
ufw allow from any to any port 443 proto tcp
```

and the rules were updated.

Whenever I want to connect to the `openconnect` from different client, it connects without any error but the following error is found after executing `journalctl -xe` command:

```
Mar 23 23:49:09 vubuntup systemd-udevd[3086]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 23 23:49:09 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=86 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23018 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54561 DPT=53 LEN=66 
Mar 23 23:49:09 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=86 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23019 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=45309 DPT=53 LEN=66 
Mar 23 23:49:10 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=86 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23020 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35143 DPT=53 LEN=66 
Mar 23 23:49:10 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=73 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23022 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53252 DPT=53 LEN=53 
Mar 23 23:49:10 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=73 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23023 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53252 DPT=53 LEN=53 
Mar 23 23:49:10 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=86 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23242 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=49740 DPT=53 LEN=66 
Mar 23 23:49:10 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23247 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52776 DPT=53 LEN=56 
Mar 23 23:49:10 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=80 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23248 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39666 DPT=53 LEN=60 
Mar 23 23:49:10 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=82 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23249 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54183 DPT=53 LEN=62 
Mar 23 23:49:12 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=vpns0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.12.0.110 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23498 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=43564 DPT=53 LEN=58 
Mar 23 23:49:13 vubuntup kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=96:00:00:a2:aa:12:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=79.124.62.82 DST=168.119.122.56 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=31435 PROTO=TCP SPT=46111 DPT=6451
```

The problem resolved whenever I disable firewall (using `sudo systemctl stop ufw`), but I am trying to find safer way of resolving this issue.

**sudo iptables -xvnL**

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 1021 packets, 47864 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   39620  9742848 ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   39620  9742848 ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   20032  7222149 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   19700  7205009 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   19700  7205009 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   19700  7205009 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 374 packets, 26353 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   29636 19146411 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   29636 19146411 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       4      208 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       2      120 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       6      328 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-d8d1af57a27c  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-d8d1af57a27c  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-d8d1af57a27c !br-d8d1af57a27c  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-d8d1af57a27c br-d8d1af57a27c  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   29624 19145755 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   29624 19145755 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   28854 19005308 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   28854 19005308 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   28854 19005308 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   28854 19005308 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   32431 17634866 ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   32431 17634866 ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   13902 14762947 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   13902 14762947 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   13902 14762947 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   13902 14762947 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       6      328 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-d8d1af57a27c !br-d8d1af57a27c  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   29636 19146411 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      br-d8d1af57a27c  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       6      328 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   29636 19146411 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       2      156 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
       1       40 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
     311    16020 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      53     4058 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     799    34366 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     770   140447 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.10.10.0/24        0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.10.10.0/24       
    1331   104563 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   13668  1801149 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      24     2325 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
      24     2325 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
     231    19032 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
    3423   172829 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
    3423   172829 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   14216  2388299 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       9      684 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      24     2325 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3423   172829 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
       0        0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     314    16216 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
       9      684 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.10.10.0/24        0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53 /* 'dapp_Bind9' */
      53     4196 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 /* 'dapp_Bind9' */
      67     3324 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
     753    44844 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
       1      167 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:4443
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4443
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:28225
       0        0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:28225
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: you are blocking DNS (Domain Name Service) requests to the google DNS at 8.8.8.8

Comment: @DougSmythies Would you please give me more details? I really don't know what is happening?

Comment: did you uncomment `tunnel-all-dns = true` as per the instructions in your link? If yes, try allowing port 53 stuff.

Comment: @DougSmythies yeah it is uncommented, I have tried `sudo ufw allow 53` but the problem still existed!

Comment: If you edit your question and add the output for `sudo iptables -xvnL`, I'll have a look, but I really do not like ufw generated iptables rules.

Comment: @DougSmythies I will add it in now.

Comment: Looks O.K. to me. see ufw-user-input chain and port 53 path taken 53 (udp) and 67 (tcp) times. Return path would be via RELATED/ESTABLISHED, so O.K.

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 from the VPN client?

Comment: @LinuxBabe Yes! but can't access to Google from browser.

Comment: Try this command: sudo ufw insert 1 allow in from 10.12.0.0/24

Comment: @LinuxBabe The problem is still remained and isn't fixed. :(